# Dictionary of lists from tab delimited file

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I'm attempting to load a tab delimited text file into a python program. It has the following format,

```
AAAAAA    1234    5678     90AB    QQQQ    JKL1
BBBBBB    QWER    TYUI     ASDF    QQQQ
CCCCCC    ZXCV    1234     PPPP
 ...
ZZZZZZ    1111
```

In short, variable numbers of columns for each row, but always at least two and each column within a row is unique. The first column I would like to use as a key, and load the rest into a list with the key pointing to it. I tried looking into the csv module already as was suggested in other threads, but I've not quite found a way to make it work for me. So yeah, apologies if this should be more obvious, very much a newbie question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simple `str.split` should work just fine for splitting the columns.  Using that, you just need to read each row and split it into columns taking the first element as the key and the rest as the value:

```
with open(file) as fin:
     rows = ( line.split('\t') for line in fin )
     d = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
```

Comment: Better to use `line.split('\t')` in case the values contain spaces.

Comment: @interjay -- Fair enough.  I skipped over the place where it said "tab-delimited".  I thought they were just sequences of spaces :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

d = {}
with open('tab_delimited_file.txt', 'rb') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t'):
        d[row[0]] = row[1:]

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'AAAAAA': ['1234', '5678', '90AB', 'QQQQ', 'JKL1'],
 'CCCCCC': ['ZXCV', '1234', 'PPPP'], 
 'BBBBBB': ['QWER', 'TYUI', 'ASDF', 'QQQQ'],
 'ZZZZZZ': ['1111']}
```

Comment: @semiflex: It sounds like the format of your tab-delimited file is messed up. I general don't post code here unless I've tested it and it works (if it's runnable on my system).

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

This is just an example of how you can take a delimited file, and print the row data.
Obviously this can be expanded and put into a dict or a list or something..

More info (and where this was taken from): http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html